# For loop where i need to print out number from 1 to 20

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So what i need to do in this task is to print out the numbers from 1-20. And the code should also fulfill the rules:

1. For numbers divisible by 3, print out "Fizz".
2. For numbers divisible by 5, print out "Buzz".
3. For numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, print out "FizzBuzz" in the
   console.
4. Otherwise, just print out the number.

```js
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++) {
                if ( i % 3) {
                    console.log("Fizz");
                }
                else if( i % 5) {
                    console.log("Buzz");
                }
                else if(i % 3 || 5) {
                    console.log("FizzBuzz");
                }
                else {
                    console.log(i);
                }
            }
```

The error i am getting :"*You printed FizzBuzz when you should have printed 1*"

Comment: Error here `else if(i % 3 || 5)`

Comment: Why? Can you explain please?

Comment: This is a common programming exercise, the entire point of which is to figure it out. There are myriad examples online. This isn't a unique question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some errors in your code

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) { // needs to start with 1
    // You should check this condition first 
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) { //needs '==' and '&&' operator
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) { // you need to check for equality to zero
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) { // here too, needs '=='
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a still  "You printed FizzBuzz when you should have printed 1" error ...

Answer (score 1):

**A one line solution**

```
for(i=1;i<=20;i++)console.log((!(i%3)?'Fizz':'')+(!(i%5)?'Buzz':'') || i);
```

Tests for matches using two [conditional (ternary) operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). The results are concatenated, eliminating the need for a third "matches both" test. A logical OR is used to print the index when the string result is empty, i.e., no matches. A single console statement outputs the final result.

As for the errors in OP's code, @elclanrs already pointed out the problem in a comment. `else if(i % 3 || 5)` is incorrect (suggest printing the result in the console to see why).

**Run the snippet to try**

```js
// Here we output to the screen rather than the console
for(i=1;i<=20;i++)window.stdout.innerHTML+='<li>'+((!(i%3)?'Fizz':'')+(!(i%5)?'Buzz':'')||i);
```

```html
<ol id="stdout">
```